# PHP empty field after ajax replace

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have form with few inputs and two selects. When I select brand i want to see model options. Everything is working. But when i click submit, vehicle_model field is empty. Fields in $_POST are filled except vehicle_model field. I don't know why.

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <select class="form-control brand-select" name="brand" required="">
    <option selected="true" value="1">MAN</option>
    <option value="2">Volvo</option>
    <option value="3">Renault</option>
    <option value="4">DAF</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group" id="ajax_model">
  <select class="form-control" name="vehicle_model" required="">
    <option selected="" value="1">XS1</option>
    <option value="2">XS2</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

```js
$(".brand-select").change(function() {
  var id_brand = $(this).val();
  var vehicle_type = <?php echo $type;?>;
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "vehicle/ajax_model",
    data: {
      'id_brand': id_brand,
      'vehicle_type': vehicle_type
    },
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function(data) {
      $("#ajax_model").html(data);
    }
  });
});
```

My full code for form. AJAX is working - I get models after selected brand. But when I click "save" PHP doesn't see `$vehicle_model`. But only when i run AJAX. When I refresh page and don't change brand, everything is working.

```html
<table id="tabela" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
  <tbody>
    <form action="http://192.168.0.200:9000/vehicle/update_information" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
      <tr>
        <td>Number:</td>
        <td>
          <div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" value="12345" name="number"></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>VIN:</td>
        <td>
          <div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" maxlength="17" minlength="17" value="12345678901234567" name="vin"></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Brand:</td>
        <td>
          <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control brand-select" name="brand" required>
              <option selected="true" value='1'>MAN</option>
              <option value='2'>Volvo</option>
              <option value='3'>Renault</option>
              <option value='4'>DAF</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Model:</td>
        <td>
          <div class="form-group" id="ajax_model">
            <select class="form-control" name="vehicle_model" required>
              <option selected value="1">XS1</option>
              <option value="2">XS2</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Kilometers</td>
        <td>
          <div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" value="100 km" disabled></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Comment:</td>
        <td>
          <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" name="comment" id="comment"></textarea>
          <input type="hidden" name="id_vehicle" value="137" />

        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><button type='submit' class='btn btn-md btn-success' style="float:right;margin-top:10px;width:80px;">Save</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </form>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What data have? can I see a console log of this?

Comment: You forgot this `data: {'id_brand': id_brand, 'vehicle_type': vehicle_type, 'vehicle_model': vehicle_model}`

Comment: Where is your php code that receives the post.

Comment: please show your data for $( "#ajax_model" ).html( data );

Comment: On first refresh i have normal code. After select brand i get models (post in ajax is working). But after that i click "submit" and PHP don't see `vehicle_model` field i don't know why. When i refresh page and don't change brand, everything is working. I checked name of field vehicle_model but it is good.

Comment: You have not even shown us the submit button you’re saying you are clicking on … so how are we supposed to _possibly_ know where you messed up? Please go read [ask] and [mcve], and then edit your question to include the minimal code necessary to first of all properly reproduce your problem.

Comment: My data for `$('#ajax_model").html(data);` is `<select class="form-control" name="vehicle_model" required=""><option selected="true" disabled="disabled" value="">-- Select model --</option><option value="3">V01</option><option value="4">V02</option></select>`

Comment: You can't select a disabled control. Check the browser console for any error after you have done an AJAX call.

Comment: My console is clean. When I remove option with "disabled", PHP still see `vehicle_model` as empty field.

Comment: _“PHP still see vehicle_model as empty field”_ - since you have still not shown us any PHP code yet, what exactly you mean by that is also still unclear … Does the entry in $_POST exist, but the value is just an empty string, or - is it not present at all?

Comment: Fix your invalid HTML first of all - you can not nest `form` between `tbody` and `tr` like that. Either the form has to go around the whole table, or be contained inside a single table cell.

Comment: My `$_POST` when i don't run AJAX
`Array ( [number] => TTTTTTTT [vin] => TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT [brand] => 1 [vehicle_model] => 1 [comment] => [id_vehicle] => 137 )`
but when i change brand and select model i get:
`Array ( [number] => TTTTTTTT [vin] => TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT [brand] => 2 [comment] => [id_vehicle] => 137 )` as you see `vehicle_model` not exist.

Comment: You need to show your php code that receives and respond to the ajax call

Comment: ~CBroe thank you! Problem solved!

Answer (score -1):

Because you forgot to send ***vehicle_model*** 
just try like this

```
<script>
    $( ".brand-select" ).change(function() {
        var id_brand = $(this).val();
        var vehicle_model=$("select[name=vehicle_model]").val()
        var vehicle_type = <?php echo $type;?>;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "vehicle/ajax_model",
            data: {
                 'id_brand': id_brand, 
                 'vehicle_type': vehicle_type,
                  'vehicle_model':vehicle_model},
            dataType: 'text',
            success: function(data){
                $( "#ajax_model" ).html( data );
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```